# Can a vector be moved and modified without an extra allocation?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
let u: Vec<u8> = (64..74).collect();
let v: Vec<u8> = u.iter().map(|i| i + 1).collect();
```

`u` was not moved, therefore `v` was inevitably newly allocated.

But if I do the following:

```
let w: Vec<u8> = u.into_iter().map(|i| i + 1).collect();
```

`u` was moved and `w` is the name of its transformation. Here is some pseudo-code representing what I mean:

```
mark u as "moved"
for i = 0..10:
    u[i] += 1
w = u
```

There is (in my opinion) no need for a new allocation, since we map a type to itself. This wouldn't be the case for this code:

```
let t: Vec<u8> = (64..74).collect();
let s: String = t.into_iter().map(|i| i as char).collect();
```

**To summarize my question**

Is there an allocation of a new `Vec` when we convert a `Vec` into an iterator and then map this iterator to an iterator **on elements of the same type** and then collect the result into a `Vec`?

And if there is indeed an allocation, why?

I tried to `--emit=mir`, but I wasn't able to find the answer. I'm using rustc 1.20 nightly (if that matters).

[If you want to play with code: Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDNCsIwEITvPsXaU4oa/4qW@HfyCQQvIhpq1ECaSLKpB/XZa06iWLF73dn5ZtZ6h2V51JBzqUkMtwaEUQLBs7XIpj6dwwzIKKF0nMQ0M0qJDEk8eemKN52nEoUlMc35hdzlXbb6XzcXKzUq3STRjS0eURv8r0XxRrl@UjSa3X9Ut1tJg2mnA8JaYzfL3jAdbBl4J8AcITeFOEDBlRcM9n5fnesa7F/BsOabHFthMDoFGVbmB@4gO3NbqwXWb4E/Wrhg/yjLJw)

Comment: While it's an interesting question about optimization, note that you can implement your intent more clearly and don't worry about such optimizations if you just write `for i in &mut u { *i += 1; }`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov if I understand correctly, your code is approximately the Rust translation of my pseudo-code, without the original "functional style". Also note that in my example, `u` is not mutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see [the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1715-1734) of the implementation of `into_iter()` for `Vec<T>`:

```
fn into_iter(mut self) -> IntoIter<T> {
    unsafe {
        let begin = self.as_mut_ptr();
        assume(!begin.is_null());
        let end = if mem::size_of::<T>() == 0 {
            arith_offset(begin as *const i8, self.len() as isize) as *const T
        } else {
            begin.offset(self.len() as isize) as *const T
        };
        let cap = self.buf.cap();
        mem::forget(self);
        IntoIter {
            buf: Shared::new(begin),
            cap: cap,
            ptr: begin,
            end: end,
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the `IntoIter` iterator incurs several extra allocations, but not for the elements of the vector; instead, the vector's underlying memory details are registered. How about [the code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#479-483) behind `map()`?

```
fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F> where
    Self: Sized, F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B,
{
    Map{iter: self, f: f}
}
```

No extra vectors allocated here either. The last piece of the puzzle is [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#1255-1257):

```
fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B where Self: Sized {
    FromIterator::from_iter(self)
}
```

No answers here; what about [the implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1689-1694) of `from_iter()` for `Vec<T>`?

```
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for Vec<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: I) -> Vec<T> {
        <Self as SpecExtend<T, I::IntoIter>>::from_iter(iter.into_iter())
    }
}
```

This is beginning to look like magic, but perhaps the related [SpecExtend code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/vec.rs.html?search=#1773-1798) will reveal what we're looking for:

```
impl<T, I> SpecExtend<T, I> for Vec<T>
    where I: Iterator<Item=T>,
{
    default fn from_iter(mut iterator: I) -> Self {
        // Unroll the first iteration, as the vector is going to be
        // expanded on this iteration in every case when the iterable is not
        // empty, but the loop in extend_desugared() is not going to see the
        // vector being full in the few subsequent loop iterations.
        // So we get better branch prediction.
        let mut vector = match iterator.next() {
            None => return Vec::new(),
            Some(element) => {
                let (lower, _) = iterator.size_hint();
                let mut vector = Vec::with_capacity(lower.saturating_add(1));
                unsafe {
                    ptr::write(vector.get_unchecked_mut(0), element);
                    vector.set_len(1);
                }
                vector
            }
        };
        <Vec<T> as SpecExtend<T, I>>::spec_extend(&mut vector, iterator);
        vector
    }

    default fn spec_extend(&mut self, iter: I) {
        self.extend_desugared(iter)
    }
}
```

In this code we can finally see the `Vec::new` and `Vec::with_capacity` methods called which allocate fresh space for the resulting vector.

**TL;DR**: no, it is not possible to move *and* modify a vector without an extra allocation.

Comment: Your post makes no argument whether any of the compiler stages could optimize those away | *TL;DR: no* - he asked whether there is an allocation.

Comment: @the8472 You already made a good general argument about the necessary optimization in your answer; I just showed the required steps that prove the complexity of the process, which makes it practically impossible (at this point). In TL;DR I'm refeering to the question's title, though I agree - I'll make it more clear when I'm on a PC.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear which part of the question you were trying to answer

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the source.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an allocation of a new Vec when we convert a Vec into an iterator and then map this iterator to an iterator on elements of the same type and then collect the result into a Vec?

Yes, the necessary optimization to avoid that allocation is simply too high-level to perform for any of the compiler tiers since they would have to reason about heap allocations and the pointer magic going on in the unsafe code blocks that underpin the `Vec` implementation. Doubly so in the general case where drop-handlers, panics inside the `map` and similar things come into play.

It might be possible to optimize at the library level by [specializing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844)
`collect() -> Vec<T>` for specific types such as `std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<T>, _>`, but those optimizations would have to be applied on a case-by-case basis where it is known to be safe.

> if I understand correctly, your code is approximately the Rust translation of my pseudo-code, without the original "functional style".

For the functional style there is a plan to add [for_each](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42986) to iterators, so if you take an [iter_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut) something equivalent could be achieved with far fewer heroics on the library or compiler side.

And it would actually reflect the intent of doing something in place more directly instead of just doing some optimization magically which then could surprisingly break under slight modification.